# How can I select the nth digit from a number in R?

Tags: r

Given some number with at least 2 digits how do I pick a specific digit?

```
x <- 4856

nth_digit(x, 4)

6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)
x <- 4856
n <- 3
str_sub(x, n,n)
#> [1] "5"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can use `substr`, specify the `start/stop` as the position of digit to extract.  It returns output as `character` class, which we convert to `integer` with `as.integer`

```
as.integer(substr(x, 4, 4))
#[1] 6
```

---

Or with `sub`

```
sub('^.{3}(.)', '\\1', x)
```